# Should the service beans defined in the jar library be instantiated by the jar library configuration or by the client war application configuration?

Tags: java, spring

I have a library as a jar packaging Maven project which offers services.

The @Configuration class to instantiate service beans:

```
@Configuration
public class JpaService {

  @Bean
  public UserRoleServiceImpl userRoleService() {
    return new UserRoleServiceImpl();
  }

  @Bean
  public UserServiceImpl userService() {
    return new UserServiceImpl();
  }

}
```

I reckoned I needed to have the beans instantiation outside of the jar archive.

So I had a copy of this class in the test part of the project, and another copy in another war packaging Maven project using the library.

But what if I instantiated the services in the jar library itself. I would need to only do it once, be it for testing or for all client projects using it.

UPDATE: Two questions...

Should all component scanning only be done from the war ? Or should the jar service components be scanned from the jar ?

And what if two components (one in the jar and one in the war) have the same class name in the same package ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think i fully understand your question, but if you are aiming to add beans to your application context that is outside the jar then what you have to do is use the @ComponentScan annotation, and specify the package you want to scan, the package can be in a different jar, the only thing required is that you anotate the clases you want to include with @Service, @Componenet or even @Configuration

example:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.somepackacge.controller",
```

...

you can include as much packages as you like.

By the way dont copy your clases from one place to the other, maintining that will be a headache in the futute, if you want to include your configuration in your tests you can always do :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = MyConfigClass.class)
```

Where MyConfigClass is the class u used before with the component scan

Hope it helps

Comment: Should the service beans defined in the jar library be instantiated by the jar library configuration or by the client war application configuration ?

Comment: You'll probably want every bean instantiated by spring so that everything is accesible in the application context. war, or jar doesnt really matter if you respect the same packages. when spring loads it will scan those packages.

Comment: So if your spring configuration is in the war (which you are)  Spring will scan packages of the jars (if specified by the scan annotation) too

Comment: Should all component scanning only be done from the war ? Or should the jar service components be scanned from the jar ?

Comment: And what if two components (one in the jar and one in the war) have the same class name in the same package ?

Comment: a) Your IDE will complain b) Spring application context will probably fail c) im not sure about this one, but if running maven, i dont know if it will compile.

Comment: Yes it always compiles. There is no static error. It's only a Spring context related matter.

Comment: If they are in the same classpath then you should have colision problems at runtime.(i think it will load one and ignore the other. not sure) The only way i can imagine that working is having two seperate class loaders, and i wouldnt go that road, nither imagine how this will play well with spring though i imagine you can. Remember we dont have modules in java natively, so same package same class name would be somthing you might want to avoid. If you still want to do this there is probably somthing you can do editing the manifest file. take a look at JigSaw. or even OSGi for that matter

Comment: Is it a good practice to add a package name in a @ComponentScan of a war, if the package is sitting in and provided by a jar ?

Comment: I dont really know if its a good practice, but im doing it to separate models and repositories(Daos) that i may use in other apps, i have a spring-boot and spring-batch as separate apps

Comment: So you have your '@Component' in a jar and your '@ComponentScan' in your other app ? That means your other app needs to be aware of the package where the component sits...

Comment: i have two different apps, with two different ComponentScan im reusing my jars, i separate the model and the repos to a different jar, so that i can re-use them. Is like i take my models and repos with me :P

Comment: I do the same, I have a user-data project containing the model and repositories, all in a jar archive, and a user-rest project containing the controllers and security all in a war archive. There is a component scan in each, and the two have different packages.

Comment: Is it enough that your configuration classes sit in different packages ? Or do they also need to have different names ?